# Is it possible to force NSwag generate OpenAPI schema/SwaggerUi for ASP.NET MVC Controllers (not ApiController!)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, swagger-ui, openapi, nswag, .net-4.8

I have the very basic setup according to the official [wiki](https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/wiki/OwinGlobalAsax) for ASP.NET MVC project with GlobalAsax.cs (.NET Framework).
Due to some reasons, I have to use MVC controllers (`System.Web.Mvc.Controller` inherited) for the API (requirement of the external framework, cannot be changed). **NSwag** ignores MVC controllers, is there a way to force it to add them to the schema except for using `WebApiOpenApiDocumentGenerator` manually?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is really simple: instead of using assembly type for UseSwaggerUi/UseSwaggerUi3, pass all controller types explicitly (there's an overload, that accepts `IEnumerable<Type> types`).